# How to split up a column of a dataframe into new columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with one column and n rows, like this one:

```
data.frame(rep(x=c("c","a","c","b","c","d"),times=c(1,4,1,4,1,4)))
```

Now, I want to split up this column of the dataframe that for every `c` a new column is created. The aim is to transform the dataframe that only has one  column into this form:

| c | c | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | d |
| a | b | d |
| a | b | d |
| a | b | d |

Comment: had to reformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we could create a new group everytime `c` appears in the `x` column, then we can pivot the data wide. Generally, duplicate names are discouraged, so I created a sequential `c` column names.

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- df %>% 
  group_by(idx = cumsum(x == "c")) %>% 
  filter(x != "c") %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = idx, values_from = x, names_prefix = "c_") %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
  c_1   c_2   c_3  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     d    
2 a     b     d    
3 a     b     d    
4 a     b     d
```

However, if you really want duplicate names, then we could add on `set_names`:

```
purrr::set_names(results, "c")

  c     c     c    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     d    
2 a     b     d    
3 a     b     d    
4 a     b     d
```

Or in **base R**, we could create the grouping with `cumsum`, then split those groups, then bind back together with `cbind`. Then, we remove the first row that contains the `c` characters.

```
names(df) <- "c"
do.call(cbind, split(df, cumsum(df$c == "c")))[-1,]

#  c c c
#2 a b d
#3 a b d
#4 a b d
#5 a b d
```

Answer (score 0):

You your columns have the same number of values, as in the example given do:

```
unstack(df, x ~ cumsum(x=="c"))

  X1 X2 X3
1  c  c  c
2  a  b  d
3  a  b  d
4  a  b  d
5  a  b  d
```

You can then remove the first row